# Connecting to ios emulator on mac from my ubuntu react native dev machine

Tags: react-native-ios, ubuntu-18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 machine and a mack book pro 
I am trying to learn react native and i want to have my dev machine as ubuntu ,Is there any way that i can do my dev work on ubuntu but connect react native from ubuntu to my mac book pro in order to run ios emulator?

Comment: Can you push the project to github from your Ubuntu machine, and clone it on to your mac to run the emulator?

Comment: well yes that is the option which came to my mind too , but as i said my dev machine is ubuntu so the chnages i will be making on that machine , so for every small chnage on my dev machine i have to make git pull on mac machine, i was wondering if there was some mechnaism or system so doing "react-native run-ios" would connect to mac machine on local lan and show output on ios emulator?